# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): mongoose.connect is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, mongoose, react-native-web

I've tried a bunch of different changes, but nothing seems to be working. I've tried switching to an import statement. I've tried putting the code in App.js. I've tried using the mongodb library instead of mongoose. I've followed a dozen tutorials on connecting to mongodb. For some reason, the connect statement keeps throwing this error. What am I missing?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

export async function post({username, password}) {
  const data = {username, password};
  const uri =
    'mongodb+srv://[username removed]:[password removed]@[project name removed].krcm7.mongodb.net/database?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
  mongoose
    .connect(uri, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then((result) => console.log('connected to db'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

  return;
}
```

To add context, this is how the function is being called.

```
function submitForm(username, password) {
  post(username, password).then(() => {
    console.log('post function ran');
  });
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me bar the odd indentation, but I'm sure that's valid. That error should not be happening - what do you get if you `console.log(mongoose)`, and what version of npm, node and mongoose do you have?

Comment: What do you get in your catch? console.log(err)

Comment: The catch isn't running since the error happens at line 7 (mongoose).

I'm running yarn v1.22.10, node v14.15.0, and mongoose v^5.12.5

Comment: Tried backdating mongoose and still had the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Mongodb and mongoose are designed to work specifically in node.js and won't work in a browser environment.